# Adding Lightbox feature to dynamically retrieved featured images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to retrieve featured images of posts dynamically and add lightbox feature to them?

Comment: You need way more detail here. You can find hundereds of lightbox plugins for jquery online, but you have not explained how the images are being retrieved at all; database, user input, external api?

Comment: i need to retrieve images from wordpress backend

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

**For Lightbox2**

Add a data-lightbox attribute to any image link to activate Lightbox.

```
 <a href="img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" title="My caption">image #1</a>
```

**For older version of lightBox**

Add rel="lightbox" attribute to any link tag to activate the lightbox

```
<a href="images/image-1.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="my caption">image #1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

off course you can. You image must contain fields that are required in LightBox.
You table must have image path, title,

if you using php

```
<a href="<?php echo $fetch['image_path'];?>" data-lightbox="image-1" title="<?php echo $fetch['image_title'];?>"></a>
```

write this code in while loop. I hope it will help you.

Comment: 'image path' should be replaced with get_the_post_thumbnail ?

Comment: i need lightbox for here:
        <a><?php echo the_post_thumbnail('accomodation'); ?></a>